# Calling "new" call within a static function compared to Calling "new" call in an instance method

Tags: java, new-operator

is it the same? or does the new in static functions allocates differently than the one on instance methods?

Answer (score 6):

No, the effect is the same. There is no difference between allocating from static vs nonstatic method scope. If you are thinking about something like allocating on the stack vs on the heap (as in C/C++), this difference is not so prominent in Java, and is not influenced by where you are calling `new` from. By default, every time you are using `new`, you are allocating an object on the heap - with some exceptions in modern JVMs (Java6 and up), caused by optimizations like [*escape analysis*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_analysis) (which may allocate an object on the stack if it is thread and local scope confined). However, local primitive variables and references are always pushed onto the stack.